# how create rest / soap throw create forgot password webservices in magento?

Tags: php, web-services, email, magento, soap

I am using following code in **soap api** for **forgot password** for **magento** and how can send mail for change password link perticular user throw api using magento functionality mail using  if any simple mathed for related **rest api** guide me

```
error_reporting(0);

$client = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/mycart/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('admin', '123456789');

$return_array = array ();

$result = $client->call($session, 'customer.list');

$email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
//$email=addslashes("test@mail.com");

if(!empty($email)){

    foreach ($result  as $key=>$value){
        //echo $value[email];
        if ($value[email]==$email)
        {   

            $return_array['message']="You will receive an email with a link to reset your password ";
            $return_array['status']= "1";
            echo json_encode($return_array);
            exit;
        }elseif ($value[email]!=$email) {

            $return_array['message']="You are not registered with us. Please sign up to create an account";
            $return_array['status']= "2";
            echo json_encode($return_array);
            exit;
        }

    }

}
else {

    $return_array['message']="You are not registered with us. Please sign up to create an account ";
    $return_array['status']= "0";
    echo json_encode($return_array);
    exit;
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you are using admin credentials for client login also you are using magento api V1 whether Magento  v1 or v2 api needs api user. Please follow the guidance 
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user